# Inferring from conditional types in TypeScript 2.9.2

Tags: typescript, type-inference

How can I infer the type of T in TypeScript 2.9.2 here:

```
type Class<T extends object> = new(...args: any[]) => T
type Conditional<T> = T extends number ? Class<Number> : T extends string ? Class<String> : never
function<T>(conditional: Conditional<T>) {}
f(Number) // I want to infer T here from given Number
```

I want to infer T = number but instead I get an error saying NumberConstructor is assignable to never!

Does TypeScript automatic type inference works here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think inference from conditional types is implemented in TypeScript.  It's not really possible to implement in the general case anyway (how clever do you have to be to determine a function's input given its output?  probably more clever than a compiler).  In any case you probably don't need it.  What if you did something like this:

```
type Class<T extends object> = new (...args: any[]) => T
type Unconditional<T extends Class<Number> | Class<String>> = 
  T extends Class<Number> ? number : T extends Class<String> ? string : never
function f<CT extends Class<Number> | Class<String>, T=Unconditional<CT>>(
  conditional: CT
) {}

f(Number) // infers as CT=NumberConstructor, T=number
```

In this case you are using the `Unconditional` conditional type to produce `T` from `CT`... that is, instead of trying to infer the input from the output, you just calculate the output from the input.

You didn't specify where you need `T`... so I can't tell whether it's best to have the function be `f<CT, T>`, or instead just `f<CT>` and tell you to use `Unconditional<CT>` wherever you were planning to use `T`.

Anyway, hope that gives you some ideas.  Good luck.

Comment: Is this still true in current versions? Seems like `T` is not inferred as `unknown` in similar cases in Typescript 4.5.4. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUB8UC8UDeAjRALihQF8AocgMwFcA7AY2AEsB7OqYCAZ2AEZUaABSIA5sRRQIADy50AJt1xVWrYnRoBbPBASkoAfhJR1EAG66AlMTOtm83BVqMW7Tj2AAmQSITjjMnKKyqrqWjp6hlB05romJNZQtvaO1PRMbBxcvADMPmISUrIQCko4KmrR4br6RvDI6PExFgiJyQ44TumuWR4ALPl+hYElweWhVdo1Uc1xxPWCbXYdFOQA9GvG2OOVGlN65Nn8QjvEnjmklgDclBtbuAQIYfsUR54nj8R9npc365uSbYVZ4RV4eHIfIghSrnUi-W4ArCTCKHfqQp5Qb7woA)